# If {cell} is contained with {range} then print cell?

Tags: excel

I have two lists/columns of data on different sheets

- **URL**

  - www.example.com/some-long-string-example-1330884
  - www.example.com/some--other-long-string-example-1370728
  - www.example.com/some-long-string-example-1159039
  - www.example.com/some-long-string-example-1195762
  - www.example.com/some-long-string-example-1195763
  - ...over 8K more of these
- **ID**

  - 1330884
  - 1370728
  - 1159039
  - 1195762
  - 1195763
  - Over 8K more of these

Assume that the ID's in column B are not in a matching order.

I want to reference the ID cell against the range of URLs, then if that ID is contained in the URL, I want to display the whole URL in a column next to the ID.

Comment: How does your data actually look? Can you post some examples? (If it's sensitive data, just give us the gist of how the string and ID are connected, i.e. `myString-id1`, or `mystring(Id1)`, etc.)  What have you tried?

Comment: Use match with wildcards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the formula in `Cell E2` as represented in image,

`=INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*"&D2&"*",A:A,0),1)`
[image]

Comment: That will also match id's which are substrings of other ids

Comment: @TimWilliams yes you are right. Assuming 8K values of the 7byte ID will not have substrings. And should be unique as well

Comment: @AgileMan can you please upvote if you found this useful!! Thanks